# ASP EF Increment / Decrement Value with + / - buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I'm new to ASP and EF and I am wondering how to do this incredibly basic operation, as well as a few questions to go along with doing it.

Currently I have a table we will call Resource;

```
class Resource
{
    int current;
    int min;
    int max;
};
```

Right now I have the default CRUD options for this. What I would like is a + / - button on the main list that will manipulate the current value of each resource and update the value in the DB and on screen.

There are also certain operations I'd like to run such as "AddFive" to a selected group of resources.

So my questions;

1. How do I do this?
2. Is this scalable? If someone is constantly hitting the buttons this is obviously going to send a lot of requests to my DB. Is there any way to limit the impact of this?
3. What are my alternatives?

Thanks.

Edit:
To clarify the question; here are my post functions. How / where do I add these in my view to get a button showing for each resource. I just want the action to fire and refresh the value rather than redirect to a new page.

```
@Html.ActionLink("+", "Increment", new { id = item.ID })

public void Increment(int? id)
{
    if (id != null)
    {
        Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
        if (movie != null)
        {
            Increment(movie);
        }
    }
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("Increment")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Increment([Bind(Include = "ID,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price")] Resource resource)
{
    if ((resource.Current + 1) < (resource.Max))
        resource.Current++;
    return View(resource);
}
```

Comment: Please show us specific code which you would like help with and ask only one question within your post.

Comment: @CountZero They're all part of the same question; how do I increment / decrement a value with a button. I've got no code to show you unless you want to see pre-generated CRUD code?

Comment: Haveyou tried to create an "add five" method on your controller? We can help with specific code issues but supplying complete solutions it outside of the scope of SO. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - We are more than hapy to help but the question is too general.

Comment: @CodeZero I've updated the entry with my increment / Decrement posts. Just to confirm; the Bind(Include="Current") means it will only post the Current value and no others?

Comment: Think I know what you're asking. Putting a sample app together now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the main issue you are having is creating a list of movies on the front end and updating the details for a specific one.

The key here is that you will need to either wrap a form around each item and have that posting to your update controller or use ajax / jquery to call the controller instead.

I have given you an example of the first one. Once the update controller is hit it will redirect to the listing page which will then present the updated list of movies.

Below is a minimal working example of how to wire this up. I've not included any data access code for brevity but have included psuedo code in the comments to show you where to place it.

Please let me know if you have any futher questions.

**Controller**

```
public class MoviesController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        // Data access and mapping of domain to vm entities here. 
        var movieListModel = new MovieListModel();
        return View(movieListModel);
    }

    public ActionResult Increment(IncrementMovieCountModel model)
    {
        // Put breakpoint here and you can check the value are correct
        var incrementValue = model.IncrementValue;
        var movieId = model.MovieId;

        // Update movie using entity framework here
        // var movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
        // movie.Number = movie.Number + model.IncrementValue;
        // db.Movies.Save(movie);

        // Now we have updated the movie we can go back to the index to list them out with incremented number
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

}
```

**View**

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.MovieListModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Some Movies</h2>


    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Increment Value</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var movie in Model.MovieList)
        {
            using (Html.BeginForm("Increment", "Movies", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                 <tr>
                     <td>@movie.Id @Html.Hidden("MovieId", movie.Id)</td>
                     <td>@movie.Name</td>
                     <td>@Html.TextBox("IncrementValue", movie.IncrementValue)</td>
                     <td><input type="submit" name="Update Movie"/></td>
                 </tr>
             }
        }
    </table>
```

**Models**

```
  public class MovieListModel
    {
        public MovieListModel()
        {
            MovieList = new List<MovieModel> {new MovieModel{Id=1,Name = "Apocalypse Now",IncrementValue = 3}, new MovieModel {Id = 2,Name = "Three Lions", IncrementValue = 7} };
        }

        public List<MovieModel> MovieList { get; set; }
    }

    public class MovieModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int IncrementValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class IncrementMovieCountModel
    {
        public int IncrementValue { get; set; }
        public int MovieId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I reworked your example a little bit to get it to fit my current format. I should have already mentioned that I was already printing everything to a table. You were almost there with what I wanted, instead of an inputbox I would just like the text to be printed and a button "+" should increment the value by a single digit (updating the static entry and the database - https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/csstricks-uploads/buttonincrememters.png). Oddly the submit btn doesn't seem to actually be doing anything, the Increment method isn't breakpointing either so I suspect it's not firing.

Comment: I actually managed to get it working, though I've no idea how to do it if I want to change a variable on the fly this is fine for my needs right now. Thanks very much!

Comment: Happy to help. By changing the variable on the fly I assume you mean incrementing the value by 1,5 or X. This whole scenario which I've come across a few times is best served by JQuery in my experience. Both the dynamic updating of the input value and posting to the server. Look at Jquery / AJAX / JQuery Validate and Editor Templates for a really clean solution. Glad I got you started. Good luck!

Comment: You're awesome. Appreciate the pointing in the right direction. Any specific reasons you suggest Jquery over my current implementation?

Comment: Cleanest way to add those '+' and '-' button functionality without postbacks to the server.

Comment: When should the postback be sent then? On page close? I'll definitely look about implementing them soon.

Comment: This will get you started. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/220/posting-data-with-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-razor-web-pages